# Modifying Bitmap from resources

Tags: android, graphics

I'm trying to draw some addition to my `ImageView`'s content, which is represented by `Drawable` from resources. I know that all `Drawable`s from resources are immutable by default, but even after I call `mutable()` method and get `Bitmap` from this `Drawable` to pass it to `Canvas` object I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor`. Here is the code:

```
Drawable homeImage = mHomeImage.getBackground(); // my ImageView
homeImage.mutate();
Canvas c = new Canvas(((BitmapDrawable)homeImage).getBitmap());
```

Is there any way to modify this `Bitmap` without creating it's copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Bitmap bmp1 = (((BitmapDrawable)homeImage).getBitmap())
        .copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp1);
```

You will need to create a new bitmap for the canvas. As the canvas uses the bitmap we pass to store whats drawn, the bitmap should be mutable.

Comment: Thank you for respond, but as you see I asked: Is there any way to modify this Bitmap **without creating it's copy**?

Comment: I saw ur question earlier. I just put the code above as the code in your question won't work. And I dont think you can modifiy a bitmap without creating a copy of it. If you are trying to draw something on top of an imageview. Create a new bitmap and draw the new stuff into the new bitmap and then use the framelayout to stack the views on top of each other. It will appear as a single view.

Comment: No, my target is to draw state of wifi signal on top of the image, listening to network speed every 3 secs and I'm afraid about memory consumption in the case of copying `Bitmap`, but never mind, thanks for respond.